# NFS Write Speed Dropping in case of faulty COMMIT-procedure

Tags: nfs

First of all sorry for posting an obvious study-question. I know this is bad habit, but i hope i still get help here, because i did a ton of research and could not find any answer to it.

The **scenario** is like this: An NFS-Client writes a sinle file with 50GB on the NFS-Server.
After writing 4GB with an average speed of 125 MByte/s it drops to 12MByte/s.

**Question**: How can you explain that.

The **given **answer**** to the question is this: After 4GB of writing the Server does not respond to the COMMIT and the Client periodically sends out COMMIT's until the Server responds to it, because the client want's to empty it's cache. In that time period the Data Rate drops to the level of the slowest element.

All i can find about the COMMIT-process is an explanation like this:

The client writes data and when the data is transferred to the Server, the Client sends the COMMIT. The server writes the data to the stable storage and responds to the COMMIT with the verf-Cookie. If the cookie is NOT different from the clients cookie, the client can empty it's cache.

So here is **my question**: Is it true, that if the server does not respond to the COMMIT-Procedure by sending the verf-cookie, that the client periodically sends COMMIT's and the data-rate drops significantly? If yes, to what level does the data-rate drop. I can't conclude from the answer to what level the data-rate drops.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is happening:

The data sent by the client is written into FS cache on the server side. Once COMMIT request is sent, this data is started to be flushed to the persistent storage (DISK). Depending on disk performance of the server, this might take some time. Let say, disk performance is 300MB/s. To flush 4GB it will take 13s. If this time is longer than NFS timeout, then client might send yet another COMMIT request, by assuming that the first one get lost. The COMMIT/WRITE verifier is used to ensure that server is not rebooted between this operations.

In such scenario, you can do:

- increase NFS timeout on the client  by specifying **timeo=** mount option. Though this will only *fix* retried COMMITs.
- tell server to start flush data early enough and avoid log delays.

use

```
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=0
sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=0
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_bytes=67108864
sysctl -w vm.dirty_bytes=536870912
```

The sizes should be tuned according to the server IO performance and network throughout.

To control when kernel starts to flush data to disk on the server and sends to server on the client side.

> NOTE: this options are global and will affect all file systems.